# Using Java to reduce BigIntegers using recursion. The method reduces the number completely, then loops to the number 'upwards' for unknown reasons

Tags: java, recursion, methods, collatz

My assignment is write a method that reduces a BigInteger using recursion.  If the number is even, split it in half then repeat the process, if the number is odd, then multiply it by 3, add 1, and repeat the process, while keeping track of the number of times this happens.

The recursion continues until the number reaches 1, then I return the amount of times this process has occurred.

I think my methods should work fine. They don't. They reduce the BigInteger to 1, then it begins looping upwards to a random number.  I don't understand why.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: What I mean by 'looping upwards': After the big int is reduced to 1, the method continues 'looping' and every time it loops, the number grows, also the counter diminishes as the method loops.  There's nothing in the method to account for that so I don't know why it does it. That explanation doesn't really help, but I put SystemPrintLn's everywhere and saw it do it.

```
public int Problem9(BigInteger value) {
    BigInteger zero = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigInteger one = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

    int count = reduceBigInt(value, zero, one, two, three, 1);
    
    return count;
}
public int reduceBigInt(BigInteger num, BigInteger zero,
        BigInteger one, BigInteger two, BigInteger three, int i) {
    
    if (num.equals(one))
        return i;
    else if ((num.remainder(two)) == zero)
        reduceBigInt((num.divide(two)), zero, one, two, three, i++);
    else
        reduceBigInt((num.multiply(three).add(one)), zero, one, two, three, i++);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "loop upwards?"  I don't see any loops here, so I'm confused by what you mean by that term.  It's important to be clear when you communicate a request for help.  What exactly are you seeing "looping" here.

Comment: One problem I think I see is that you're getting a bit lost in all the BigInteger code.  Try writing this same code out by hand for regular integers and see how it runs, I think you might be able to debug it.

Comment: You ignore what the recursive call returns. You should return it -- not `i`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... If the number is even, split it in half then repeat the process, if the number is odd, then multiply it by 3, add 1, and repeat the process, while keeping track of the number of times this happens. ..."*

Here is an example.

The *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#field-summary)* class conveniently offers instances for common values, *ZERO*, *ONE*, *TWO*, etc.

```java
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;
```

```java
class Mutate {
    BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
    int n = 0;

    void f(BigInteger x) {
        if (x.compareTo(ONE) == 0) return;
        n++;
        if (x.mod(TWO).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) f(x.divide(TWO));
        else f(x.multiply(three).add(ONE));
    }
}
```

The result of *f(new BigInteger("123"))* would be *46*.
Here is an output.

```
n = 0, x = 123
n = 1, x = 370
n = 2, x = 185
n = 3, x = 556
n = 4, x = 278
n = 5, x = 139
n = 6, x = 418
n = 7, x = 209
n = 8, x = 628
n = 9, x = 314
n = 10, x = 157
n = 11, x = 472
n = 12, x = 236
n = 13, x = 118
n = 14, x = 59
n = 15, x = 178
n = 16, x = 89
n = 17, x = 268
n = 18, x = 134
n = 19, x = 67
n = 20, x = 202
n = 21, x = 101
n = 22, x = 304
n = 23, x = 152
n = 24, x = 76
n = 25, x = 38
n = 26, x = 19
n = 27, x = 58
n = 28, x = 29
n = 29, x = 88
n = 30, x = 44
n = 31, x = 22
n = 32, x = 11
n = 33, x = 34
n = 34, x = 17
n = 35, x = 52
n = 36, x = 26
n = 37, x = 13
n = 38, x = 40
n = 39, x = 20
n = 40, x = 10
n = 41, x = 5
n = 42, x = 16
n = 43, x = 8
n = 44, x = 4
n = 45, x = 2
n = 46, x = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues:

- The argument `i++` will pass the original value of `i` (before increment), which means that *every* recursive call will receive the same value for their local `i`, which is 1. When the recursive call comes back, the next statement will do `return i`, when at that time `i` has been incremented once (remember it is a local variable), and so that `return` will *always* return 2.
- Although the recursive calls return a value, this value is ignored by the caller making the recursive call.
- `== zero` is not the way to compare BigIntegers. In this particular case, you could use the `testBit` method instead.
- As you start out with `i` equal to 1, your function could never return 0, yet when the input is 1 the response should be 0.
- It is a pity you have to pass `zero`, `one`, `two` and `three` over and over again as argument, consuming stack space. Instead, define them as fields. You can even get rid of all of them:

  - Instead of `equals(one)` you can use `bitLength()` as only 1 has a bit length of 1.
  - Instead of `mod(two)` and compare with `zero`, use `testBit(0)`
  - instead of `divide(two)`, use `shiftRight(1)`
  - Instead of `multiply(three)`, simply add `num` to itself twice, and to add the one we can do that after the first addition by flipping the least bit (which is guaranteed to be zero as we just doubled the number).
- If you decide to use recursion, then it is more elegant to not pass `i` as argument, but to have each recursive call execute as if it was the top-level execution -- without needing information of what was already counted before. In that approach, the base case should return 0, and the caller should add one to the returned value from recursion.

Here is how you could do that:

```
    public int Problem9(BigInteger num) {
        return num.bitLength() == 1 ? 0 // Base case
             : 1 + Problem9(
                 num.testBit(0) ? num.add(num).flipBit(0).add(num) // 3x+1
                                : num.shiftRight(1) // x/2
               );
    }
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need `one` since `BigInteger` defines a constant `BigInteger.ONE`

Comment: Unless I miss something it does `.add(one)`? This should probably be `.add(BigInteger.ONE)`

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right. I have used `flipBit` to add the 1 to an even number.